# Cannot read GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT using QOpenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am implementing a simple click selection for 3D objects inside a QOpenGLWidget. To do this I need to transform 2D mouse coordinates into 3D worldspace. I had previously implemented the whole thing using QGLWidget. Using QOpenGLWidget, I am not able to read the GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT of a pixel:

```
float z;
glReadPixels(pixel.x, height - pixel.y, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &z);
```

'z' is always 0.
To make sure my pixel coordinates were correct I tried receiving GL_RGBA values:

```
float rgba[4];
glReadPixels((int)p_temp.x(), (int) (viewport[3] - p_temp.y()), 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, rgba);
```

, which returns the correct pixel Colors.
In order for this to work I had to change the domain of the pixel coordinates from local to parent coordinates. This probably results from the fact that the GL_VIEWPORT is set corresponding to the parent widgets size:

```
int viewport[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
```

for QGLWidget this returns: `{0, 0, this->width(), this->height()}`

for QOpenGLWidget this returns: `{0, 0, this->parent()->width(), this->parent()->height()}`

BTW, my OpenGL version is 4.5 and I do not get any OpenGL error using glReadPixels with GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT

Now, I am kind of clueless as to what I might be missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Try GL_DEPTH_STENCIL instead of GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT?

Comment: How do you know that the depth isn't being read? What value are you getting, and what value do you expect to get? Also, are you sure you have a depth buffer at all?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Doesn't OpenGL give an error though if you read GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT with no depth buffer attached?

Comment: I have called ```glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)``` to enable the default depth buffer. After trying to read the depth data, I check ```glGetError()``` and it returns ```GL_NO_ERROR```. Funny enough, that's even when I comment out ```glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)```, so I am not sure if the function takles into account if there actually is a depth buffer to read the pixel data from. As mentioned above, all values are 0 for the depth, regardless which object I am clicking on.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Yes, it should: "GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if format is GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT and there is no depth buffer."

Comment: If that is the case, then I guess the existence of my depth buffer is not the issue. As I understand, depth values will always be normalized between near and far clip plane... [This](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Object_selection) article suggests that the background has a default depth value of 1. Which makes sense, because depth test ends at the far clip plane. As I mentioned, I get a GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT value of 0 for every pixel. This technically means the fragment is on the near clip plane... This does not make sense considering my geometry is visibly behind it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QOpenGLWidget works into an underlying Framebuffer Object (FBO) and you can't simply read the depth component from that FBO if multi sampling is enabled. The easiest solution is to set the samples to zero, so your code will look like this:

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setVersion(2, 1);
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);

format.setSamples(0);

QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
```

Or you can use multisampling like format.setSamples(4), but an additional FBO will be required without multisampling where the depth buffer can be copied.

```
class MyGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
//
// OTHER WIDGET RELATED STUFF
//
QOpenGLFramebufferObject *mFBO=nullptr;

MyGLWidget::paintGL()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  //
  // DRAW YOUR SCENE HERE!
  //

  QOpenGLContext *ctx = QOpenGLContext::currentContext();

  // FBO must be re-created! is there a way to reset it?
  if(mFBO) delete mFBO;

  QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat format;
  format.setSamples(0);
  format.setAttachment(QOpenGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil);
  mFBO = new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(size(), format);

  glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFramebufferObject());
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, mFBO->handle());
  ctx->extraFunctions()->glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width(), height(), 0, 0, mFBO->width(), mFBO->height(), GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);

  mFBO->bind(); // must rebind, otherwise it won't work!

  float mouseDepth = 1.f;
  glReadPixels(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &mouseDepth);

  mFBO->release();
}
};
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem as the OP and this does not fix my issue at all.

Comment: First, try setting QSurfaceFormat::samples to zero in your main.cpp before calling show() on your widget. Must work like that because the FBO won't be multisampled.

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample